# Finding the difference between the results of two queries in Access 2003

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I would like to create a query in Access 2003 that combines two queries to find the difference between the results.

Query 1: [all]

```
SELECT mars.Name, mars.Location, mars.Business_Unit 
FROM mars 
GROUP BY mars.Name, mars.Location, mars.Business_Unit;
```

That returns

```
Name   Location   Business Unit
-----  ---------  -------------
John   Sydney     AU
Grace  Brisbane   AU
Lee    Melbourne  GU
```

Query 2: [not_zero]

```
SELECT mars.Name, mars.Location, mars.Business_Unit 
FROM mars 
WHERE ((mars.orc)<>0) 
GROUP BY mars.Name, mars.Location, mars.Business_Unit;
```

It returns:

```
Name   Location  Business Unit 
-----  --------  -------------
John   Sydney    AU
Grace  Brisbane  AU
```

My query that I am trying to create:

```
SELECT m.Name, m.Location, m.Business_Unit 
FROM 
    all AS m 
    LEFT JOIN 
    Not_Zero AS o 
        ON (m.Name=o.Name) 
            AND (m.Location=o.Location) 
            AND (m.Business_Unit=o.Business_Unit) 
GROUP BY m.Name, m.Location, m.Business_Unit;
```

I would like my query to achieve:

```
Name  Location   Business Unit 
----  ---------  -------------
Lee   Melbourne  GU
```

But instead I get the same results as the [all] query:

```
Name   Location   Business Unit
-----  ---------  -------------
John   Sydney     AU
Grace  Brisbane   AU
Lee    Melbourne  GU
```

Ok, so this [mars] table is something like this:

```
Name   Location   Business Unit  ORC
-----  ---------  -------------  ---
John   Sydney     AU             0
Grace  Brisbane   AU             5
John   Sydney     AU             10 
Grace  Brisbane   AU             0
Lee    Melbourne  GU             0
Lee    Paris      EU             0
```

what I'm trying to achieve is to get the names that have orc = 0 all the way i.e. which is why I want for example:

```
Name  Location   Business Unit  ORC
----  ---------  -------------  ---
Lee   Melbourne  GU             0
Lee   Paris      EU             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the [not_zero] query results will always be a subset of the [all] query results, the "difference" between the two are the rows in [all] that do not appear in [not_zero]. The following query finds them:

```
SELECT all.*
FROM 
    all 
    LEFT JOIN 
    not_zero 
        ON (all.NAME=not_zero.NAME) 
            AND (all.LOCATION=not_zero.LOCATION) 
            AND (all.[BUSINESS UNIT]=not_zero.[BUSINESS UNIT])
WHERE 
    (not_zero.NAME Is Null) 
        AND (not_zero.LOCATION Is Null) 
        AND (not_zero.[BUSINESS UNIT] Is Null);
```